# Why does delete/insert result in a larger database size than using upsert?

Tags: google-cloud-spanner

I have a table with 1.6 million records. This table has multiple Interleaved tables. Periodically I receive updates.  If I apply the update by **deleting and then inserting**, the database size is approximately 35% larger than by using **UPSERT**.

The database Retention period is set to 1 hour. Even after the retention period has passed, the database size does not go down.

Any idea why this is?

Update: The backup size for the database is the same regardless of the update method.

Thanks

Comment: Can you share a repro?

Comment: As an update, the database eventually shrinks back to almost the same size, but it can take days for that to happen. Must have something to do with actually cleaning up the old deleted records.  Thanks for your interest in my question.

Answer (score 0):

The database retention period which is referred to as [version_retention_period](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.instances.databases#Database.FIELDS.version_retention_period) in the official documentation is the period in which all the versions of the data are guaranteed to exist.

There are various background processes which perform compactions etc and can take anywhere from a few hours to a few days to run depending on the load etc on the database. Thus, your observation is as expected.